# Why are some awards given in a wrong category?

Tags: award, classification

There are some errors in, for example, Grammy's.

For example, I recall Drake being nominated and won in the Pop/Rock category in one year.

Or recently, Justin Bieber complained Grammy's for nominating his Album, *Changes* for best Pop instead of R&B.

Why are there these errors in the most important music awards in the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Awards are subjective, and so are genres, which change over the course of time.** Meanwhile, many of the Grammy voters are older, and have conservative definitions of genres that may not keep up with the times. Early hip-hop was easily distinguishable from pop or rock, but even in the early 80s, there were famous crossover hits, such as Run DMC's "Walk This Way" that blurred the lines.  Drake is generally considered hip-hop, but most of his songs are closer to what traditionally was considered pop than to early hip-hop.

Conversely, R&B, throughout most of its long lifespan as a term in common use, was meant to describe songs that were played on Black radio and marketed to Black listeners (in America). Bieber's latest album may be close in sound and style to current conceptions of R&B, but it's not primarily aligned with a Black audience --so it would likely have **drawn controversy** if it had been nominated in his preferred category.